# Autocomplete JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html

how can i install this?
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default
Thanks, i tried but it won't work.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "Covrigel",
          "DariuS.",
          "[GF]Vlad",
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="input-group custom-search-form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="Search...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I also use [this bootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)

Comment: Improved formatting and hyperlinked the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jquery library is correctly referenced you can use:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()){
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "Covrigel",
          "DariuS.",
          "[GF]Vlad"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      });   

  });      

</script>
```

My implementations look similar to that. I did notice that you have a extra comma, which will cause havoc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Chosen : JQuery Plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) 
very Simple to use and more powerful :)